# C# concurrent filestream read/write eof

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, filestream, streamreader

I have a thread producing lines in a log file:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    using (var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(i);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    File.Delete(file);
});
```

And I have a thread reading lines from the same log file:

```
// Reads lines from the log file.
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(500); // Horrible wait to ensure file existence in this test case.
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.Read | FileShare.Write))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) Console.WriteLine(line);
        // FIXME: The stream reader stops, instead of doing a continous read.
        Console.WriteLine("End of file");
    }
});
```

The reader is supposed to read all written lines, therefore it should wait for more data instead of stopping at the first time it encounters EOF. I do not mind if the reader is never 'finished', so long as the file continues to exist, the reader is allowed to continue reading. How can I achieve this? Full code for reproduction purposes:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PlayGround
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            const string file = "test.log";

            // Writes lines to the log file.
            var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(i);
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }

                File.Delete(file);
            });

            // Reads lines from the log file.
            var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500); // Horrible wait to ensure file existence in this test case.
                using (
                    var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                        FileShare.Delete | FileShare.Read | FileShare.Write))
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) Console.WriteLine(line);
                    // FIXME: The stream reader stops, instead of doing a continous read.
                    Console.WriteLine("End of file");
                }
            });

            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: As a practical example, this is useful for a scenario where a third party process is producing log entries which need to be read and processed. You could see this as a log file reader if that makes the application and use clearer.

Comment: Well, the EOF *is* there, so I guess you'll just have to keep trying to `ReadLine` in a cycle with a sleep or something. There probably is a better way, but this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform a wait when the `line == null`, by checking the `streamReader.EndOfFile` property. Using `Thread.Sleep(1000)` is not an ideal solution, a bit hacky, and I guess there are other better alternative solutions out there. :-)

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.Read | FileShare.Write))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string line;
    bool running = true; // we may want to terminate this loop in some condition.
    while (running)
    {
        line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        if (line != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        else // as per edit, the whole else block can be omitted.
        {
            while (streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait around for n time. This could end up in an infinte loop if the file is not written to anymore. 
            }
        }
   }

   // FIXME: The stream reader stops, instead of doing a continous read.
   Console.WriteLine("End of file");
}
```

**EDIT:** You can do without the else block:

```
else 
{ 
    while (streamReader.EndOfStream) 
    { 
        Thread.Sleep(1000) 
    } 
}
```

Like this:

```
while (running)
{
    line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    if (line != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the approach, but this is effectively polling the file instead of a blocking call. If a blocking call to determine when the next read line can be read exists, that would be the perfect solution.

Comment: Using AutoResetEvent isn't an option due to 3rd party stuff?

Comment: Exactly. There is no control over the writer.

Answer (score 0):

You need synchronization mechanism, in this case I use AutoResetEvent.
The required changes based on your code is.

```
const string file = "test.log";
// Adds new line.
AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);

streamWriter.Flush();
// Adds new line.
signal.Set();

File.Delete(file);
// Adds new line
signal.Set();

Thread.Sleep(500);
// Replaces with.
signal.WaitOne();

while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) Console.WriteLine(line);
// Replaces with.
while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    signal.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

## Full code

```
const string file = "test.log";
AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);

// Writes lines to the log file.
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    using (var fileStream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(i);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                signal.Set();
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }

    File.Delete(file);
    signal.Set();
});

// Reads lines from the log file.
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    signal.WaitOne();
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.Read | FileShare.Write))
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                signal.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

            // FIXME: The stream reader stops, instead of doing a continous read.
            Console.WriteLine("End of file");
        }
    }
});

Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
```